# CQL - rows with different columns

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql

Is it possible to store in Cassandra (using CQL) two rows in a one column family with the same column quantity but with a one different column? Something like this:

```
// column family
'users' : {

    // row 1
    'john' : {
        name: 'John',
        lastname: 'Smith',
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
    }

    // row 2
    'jack' : {
        name: 'Jack',
        lastname: 'Sparrow',
        age: 33
    }
}
```

My current CQL code:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE people WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
USE people;

CREATE COLUMNFAMILY users (
    username varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar,
    lastname varchar,
    email varchar
);

INSERT INTO users (username, name, lastname, email) VALUES ('john', 'John', 'Smith', 'john@gmail.com');

ALTER TABLE users DROP email;
ALTER TABLE users ADD age int;

INSERT INTO users (username, name, lastname, age) VALUES ('jack', 'Jack', 'Sparrow', 33);

SELECT * FROM users;

OUTPUT:

 username | age  | lastname | name
----------+------+----------+------
     john | null |    Smith | John
     jack |   33 |  Sparrow | Jack
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "same column quantity but with a one different column?" Maybe read up on cassandra's sparse data model. Basically, we won't create a cell in the underlying sstable if you don't insert a value for a given cql row. I.E. if you hadn't said DROP email, Jack would not have an empty cell for email unless you deliberately inserted a null / tombstone.

Comment: So, If I skip `ALTER TABLE users DROP email;` I will get for Jack's email null value but "physically" this column won't be create for this row, I'm right?

Comment: Yep use sstable2json to introspect. Remember you'll have to flush to see the tables.

Comment: Thx a lot, that's what I mean :) You can write answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra has a sparse data model. We won't create a cell in the underlying sstable if you don't insert a value for a given cql row.

I.E. if you hadn't said DROP email, Jack would not have an empty cell for email unless you deliberately inserted a null / tombstone.

You can introspect sstables using `sstable2json` to understand how the data is laid out on disk. Remember to use `nodetool flush` before you try this or you may end up introspecting an empty directory!